# When I bootstrap Modal from CDHtmlView Class or CHTmlDialog, the scroll bar does not disappear. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, internet-explorer, bootstrap-modal

When I bootstrap Modal from CDHtmlView Class or CHTmlDialog, the scroll bar does not disappear.

[image]

I am using the Windows IE Framework to control external web pages using CDHtmlView Class or CDHtmlDialog.

Of course, "\ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Main \ FeatureControl \ FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" is set to the latest (11001)

IE11 and Chrome browser will work normally. Do you know why?

How do I fix it?

```
<label class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-form-label"></label>
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-10  col-lg-10 col-xl-10 pr-0" style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table id="group_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable ml-2">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
      <col style="width: 50px;" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center">group</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">odd</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-noitem>
        <td colspan='3'>hint message</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

// HTML onClick
<button onclick="sch_dept_modal_popup();" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">add</button>

function sch_dept_modal_popup() {
  loadSearchDept('addDept');
}

// modal Call 
function loadSearchDept(returnFunc) {
  if (!returnFunc || typeof (returnFunc) == "undefined" || returnFunc == "")
    return;
    var func = encodeURIComponent(btoa(returnFunc));
    var url = StringFormat("/util/search/dept?func={0}", func);
    $("#searchDept").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            alert("get search_dept_modal error");
        }
        else
            $('#search_dept_modal').modal({
                backdrop : 'static',
                keyboard : false
            });
    });
}
```

When the Modal window appears, the scroll bar at the back should not come forward.

Comment: The scroll bar setting is here.
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-10  col-lg-10 col-xl-10 pr-0" style="overflow-x: auto;">

Comment: Which BootStrap version are you using？ From the picture and code, it seems that the issue is relates to the popup window, please paste the related code (from the existing code, I didn't find the popup container). can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, I suggest you could also try to use F12 developer tools to check the html and css style, to detect which part of code cause this issue.